# AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow, I do not understand where is the problem of what it tells me

Tags: c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//functions of stackoveflow
#define ba_set(ptr, bit)   { (ptr)[(bit) >> 3] |= (char)(1 << ((bit) & 7)); }                               
#define ba_clear(ptr, bit) { (ptr)[(bit) >> 3] &= (char)(~(1 << ((bit) & 7))); }
#define ba_get(ptr, bit)   ( ((ptr)[(bit) >> 3] & (char)(1 << ((bit) & 7)) ?  1 : 0 ) )                    //gives the value in that position
#define ba_setbit(ptr, bit, value) { if (value) { ba_set((ptr), (bit)) } else { ba_clear((ptr), (bit)); } } //set a value in an array position

#define u32 uint32_t

int main() {
  u32 N = 10;
  u32 **arrBit = malloc(sizeof(u32 *)*(5));
  assert(NULL != arrBit);
  arrBit[0] = calloc(((N + 7) / 8), sizeof(char));// created the bit array of size N
  assert(NULL != arrBit[0]);
  ba_setbit((arrBit[0]), (0), 1); //I put the value 1 in position 0 of the bit array
  printf("%u\n", ba_get((arrBit[0]), (0)) );
  free(arrBit[0]);
  free(arrBit);
  return 0;
}
```

Using:

gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -DNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined -O3 -g -c

it gives the exit, when trying:

> ba_setbit((colores[0]), (1), 1);
>
> runtime error: load of address 0x602000000010 with insufficient space
>   for an object of type 'void'
>
> 0x602000000010: note: pointer points here  01 00 00 62  00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00
>   00
>
> 0x602000000012 is located 0 bytes to the right of 2-byte region
>   [0x602000000010,0x602000000012)
>
> SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow

I honestly can't find where it's failing

Comment: Why `sizeof(char)` when `arrBit[0]` is a pointer to `u32`? The value of `(N + 7) / 8` is `2` so `calloc(((N + 7) / 8), sizeof(char))` only allocates 2 bytes. In the macro, casting an operand to `char` does not make the target any smaller. It's still 4 byte storage.

Comment: So `u32 **arrBit` needs to be `char **arrBit` as indicated by the `[(bit) >> 3]` which obtains the array index.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not pay attention to the types, you have saved me